# How can I handle dependencies in Cucumber tests?

Tags: cucumber, external-dependencies, gherkin

When I have dependencies such as http or authenticate, how can I use Cucumber without being slowed down on these services ?

Answer (score 1):

You should mock / stub those dependencies.

WebMock can do that.  It stubs at a low HTTP client lib level.
Add `require 'webmock/cucumber'` in the support/env.rb file

Examples:

Simulate basic http

```
stub_request(:get, "www.test.com").to_return(:body => "Test")
stub_request(:post, "www.test.com").with(:body => "test", :header => "Content-Type: application/json")

stub_request(:POST, "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token").with("client_id={client_id}
&client_secret={secret}
&code={code}").to_return("access_token={token}
&token_type=bearer")
```

Simulate OAuth

```
stub_request(:GET, "httpsL//api.github.com/users/wayneye")
.with(:headers => 'Authorization: token{fake_token}')
.and_return('"name": "Wayne Ye", "public_repos":9, "company": "ThoughtWorks"')
```